# Data conversion fails when trying to import values with . precision

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have the following csv file :

```
EmployeeId,PayRate
12,2.50
15,5.33
56,7.28
```

I am trying to store data in a SQL Server table, like below :

**Using Conversion Component :**

[image]

> "The value could not be  converted because of a potential loss of
>   data."

**Using Derived Column :**

```
ISNULL(PayRate) ? (DT_R4)0.00 : (DT_R4)PayRate
```

SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.

> The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049063 occurred,
>   and the error row disposition on  "Colonne dérivée.Entrées[Entrée de
>   colonne dérivée].Colonnes[PayRate]" specifies failure on error.

I am not able to find which is the correct type to use to store the PayRate in my situation.

Comment: How many rows are you inserting? It's possible there's a row further down with bad data. Personally I would use `DECIMAL`, not `FLOAT`. Float is only useful in limited circumstances

Comment: I have about 300 rows. I am having the same using ISNULL((DT_DECIMAL,2)PayRate) ? (DT_DECIMAL,2)0.00 : (DT_DECIMAL,2)PayRate

Comment: I always suggest importing into varchar and inspecting it in the database. You can also check the text source and see what data type it thinks it is.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I think it's better to import all my data into varchar then do the CONVERT/CAST with SQL Server

Comment: a lot of possible reasons, no way to decide the exact reason before trying things out. Often I experienced because 2.50 is using the dot '.' for the decimal number while you should use a comma ',' but in CSV file it would be considered as a separated column. So I think it's better to pull it as varchar, in the derived column, replace '.' to ','  after that, do another data conversion from varchar to float or decimal

Comment: That's how I usually do it. Excel and text drivers are very unreliable so I don't waste my time anymore. You can use TRY_CAST to convert varchar to other data types without error. Just make certain that the data ends up in the correct data type. I recommend something like `DECIMAL(12,6)` over `float` because float is imprecise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a derived column to replace `.` by `,` :

```
REPLACE(PayRate,".",",")
```

Then convert it to `DT_NUMERIC` :

[image]